# Is there a standard technique for practicing the "th" phonemes?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, th

My son is still young enough to be practicing his pronunciation.  He has trouble (not surprisingly) with *th* in particular.  I have modeled the correct mouth shape for him but it still takes him a lot of effort to get the sound right. In regular speech, he just slurs the sounds into *f* or *s* depending on the word.

With his *l* sounds, we had a lot of success by singing "[Skip to My Lou](http://www.gardenofsong.com/skiptomylou.html)" a lot. I can't think of any children's songs that have frequent *th* sounds though.

Is there a current, accepted, standard technique to help him practice both the voiced and unvoiced *th* (which preferably don't involve sitting and saying "th, th, th" for a long time)?

Comment: One word of advice: don't have him practice while driving on a bumpy road. :^)

Answer (score 4):

Many people have this problem, especially children, and [this song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzDDlwbSwxA) does a pretty good job of helping kids. I would also suggest [this song by Mrs. Jones](http://www.mrsjonesroom.com/songs/thsong.html) also has a great song, that teaches the "-th" sound, and has the lyrics, on the webpage.

Also though, I might suggest using words he already knows how to say, like "Thank you" and "Teeth". Then relate those to other words.

Comment: There is this [Electric Company](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41WVZiwuQ9g) song as well, but none of them is particularly catchy.

Answer (score 1):

Current standard? Not sure. What I used on my child was to pretend English was an inflected language:

- The, they, their, them (repeat)

The "r" in *their* requires a slight movement of the tongue. The "m" in *them* requires the mouth to close. When repeated in a patter this *exercises* the tongue, thus creating muscle memory.

Then switch it up to:

- Then, this, these, those (repeat)

The recycle of "those" to "then" can be tricky for youngsters. Once this is easy, you put it all together.

See also:

- Why, where, while, when (repeat)

Tapping your tongue to the roof of your mouth to form the "n" in *when* is the perfect end/repeat marker.

All in my opinion, of course.